# Why code (ajax) not working in mobile browsers

Tags: php, ajax, mobile, browser

this is my first to write Ajax so pls help me to make it work in mobile browsers (it is working in desktop browsers)
i used PHP to connect with database

thank your :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').on('click', function () {
            
          var formdata = $(".search").val();
            
          if (formdata != "") {
            
                $.ajax({
                  url:"fetch.php",
                  method: 'POST',
                  data: {query:formdata},
                  success: function(data){
     
                 $('#output').html(data);
                    $('#output').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#output').css('height', '67px');
                    $('#output').css('font-weight', 'bold')
                    $('#output').css('color', '#089848');
                    $('#output').css('padding', '20px');
                    $('#output').css('text-align', 'center');

                    $('#output').css('margin-top', '-8px');
                  }
                });
            
          } else {
          $('#output').css('display', 'none');
            }
    
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Why, what errors / unexpected results are you getting in mobile browsers exactly? What debugging have you done? Which browsers and versions have you tested with, specifically? "Mobile" is too broad a term and covers quite a few different browsers and implementations. We can't help you without some sort of details of the actual problem. In theory the same JS/jQuery code should work in all browsers, certainly for something as standard as this anyway.

Comment: hi @ADyson , I made a test in chrome and firefox (mobile device) but doesn't show any result!. But in desktop device chrome and firefox showing right result

Comment: Ok. That's a basic test. Now you need to do some debugging to find out why it's different